# UIActivityController to share URL file

Tags: ios, swift, swift3, xcode8, uiactivityviewcontroller

I want to share an URL file that has been created in the app and a text. But it seems it only can share text and not any data like URL or `UIImage`.
The code I am using:

```
let sharedVideo = Video(Title: _data[1], VideoID: _data[0], Duration: _data[3], ViewCount: _data[2])
let  sharedURL = VideoManager.exportData(video: sharedVideo)
let shareItems:Array = [sharedURL,"check this out baby!"] as [Any]

let activityViewController = UIActivityViewController(activityItems: shareItems, applicationActivities: nil)

self.present(activityViewController, animated: true, completion: nil)
```

Also I use an `UIImage` object instead of sharedURL to see If it has problem with URL or not.

It doesn't work even with an image file. When I click on share button inside `UIActivityViewController`, It works just for text, no URL nor image.
I am using **Swift 3** in **Xcode 8**.

Thanks.

PS: I am sure about sharedURL object that it isn't nil nor undefined.

Comment: you want to share url or text into social and your app?

Comment: @seggy I want to share text with URL to social apps and also Airdrop it to other iOS device users. Thanks

Comment: ohk than you can follow @Sanjeet verma answer

Answer (score 18, accepted):

Try this:

```
 @IBAction func btnExport(sender: AnyObject)
{

     let someText:String = "Hello want to share text also"
    let objectsToShare:URL = URL(string: "http://www.google.com")!
    let sharedObjects:[AnyObject] = [objectsToShare as AnyObject,someText as AnyObject]
    let activityViewController = UIActivityViewController(activityItems : sharedObjects, applicationActivities: nil)
    activityViewController.popoverPresentationController?.sourceView = self.view

    activityViewController.excludedActivityTypes = [ UIActivityType.airDrop, UIActivityType.postToFacebook,UIActivityType.postToTwitter,UIActivityType.mail]

    self.present(activityViewController, animated: true, completion: nil)

}
```

Comment: At first I tried the code you using image to share,and It works perfectly. Now I'm gonna try your edited code to see If it works for URL or not. Thank you so much.

Comment: @BehdadAhmadi i am glad to help you if my answer is acceptable then upvote me.

Comment: Thank you buddy,your answer works,how ever again failure with my own customized URL. My url consists of a NSDictionary that holds 4 string,1 base64encoded string and an Data object. I think its something wrong with my customized URL. However Thank you for sharing your time with me.

Comment: @BehdadAhmadi Happy coding:)

Comment: Thank you so much!

Comment: This doesn't work for me. I tested on iPad only

Answer (score -1):

Simplified solution working with Swift 5+

```
let url = URL(string: shareUrlString)!
let text = "Some text that you want shared"
let activity = UIActivityViewController(activityItems: [url, text], applicationActivities: nil)
present(activity, animated: true)
```